# BeautifulSoup4 not accepting valid XML

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to open a valid xml file, parse it with `lxml-xml`, prettify it, and finally save it to a different file.

My code is as follows:

```
def main(path_to_config):
    with open(f'configs/{path_to_config}', 'r') as file:
        contents = file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
        with open(f'pretty_xml/{path_to_config.split("_")[0]}.xml', 'w') as new_file:
            new_file.write(soup.prettify())
```

Unfortunately no matter what is put into the file, the parse will not generate valid xml. The single line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is all that is saved to the `pretty_config/` files. I have validated, with multiple online validators, that the xml I am passing is valid.

I have tried replacing the `file.read()` with just the file, no luck. I have also tried replacing this with just a string of xml, which works and validates that my parser is working and something is breaking between the file opening and passing contents to `BeautifulSoup`.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE:

My xml file has a single line, `<note><time>twelve</time></note>`.

As a sanity check, I added `assert contents == '<note><time>twelve</time></note>'` as when I pass the string to `BeautifulSoup` the parser has no problem. This new line threw an `AssertionError`, which I am completely unsure how. Should the strings not be identical? I copied the string in the .py file straight to the .xml file, there are no additional whitespaces or any other characters.

Comment: @snakecharmerb `repr(contents)` returns `'\'\\ufeff<note><time>twelve</time></note>\''`

I'm not sure how to interpret those first `\'\\ufeff`, or what that even is.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb. Apparently \ufeff is a BOM (Byte Order Mark), which wasn't removed when I was copy pasting the values from the .py file to the .xml file. PyCharm has an option when you right click to 'Remove BOM', I did that and the file parsed properly.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I tried to specify different encodings and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

There was a BOM at the beginning of my file, which was not overwritten by copy pasting from the .py file to the .xml file.

I discovered this thanks to @snakecharmerb's suggestion to use `repr(contents)` to view the true representation of my string and discovered the the value was `'\'\\ufeff<note><time>twelve</time></note>\''`. The \ufeff is a [BOM](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en) and needed to be removed.

I added the following lines to the beginning of my function and it fixes the error.

```
s = open(f'configs/{path_to_config}', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
open(f'configs/{path_to_config}', mode='w', encoding='utf-8').write(s)
```